# PHP Map: back-and-forth

Tags: php

Consider this contrived example. The following array works fine if I want to convert English to Spanish.

```
$translate = array( 'one'    => 'uno',
                    'two'    => 'dos',
                    'three'  => 'tres'
            );

echo $translate['one'];
```

But how do I convert from Spanish to English? Can this be done with an associative array or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You need another associative array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo array_search ('uno', $translate);
```

However, it might be faster if you want to translate multiple words the other way around to remap the array:

```
$translate_reverse = array_flip ($translate);
echo $translate_reverse ['uno'];
```

Answer (score 2):

While you can search the array, it is O(n) as opposed to O(1) for the key. So I would do this:

```
$english_to_spanish = array('one' => 'uno', ...);
$spanish_to_english = array_flip($english_to_spanish);
```

If you have a huge list, then perhaps it's better to use a database to store both columns indexed.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a one-to-one mapping, you can use the following to get the english word:

```
echo array_search("tres", $translate);
```

However, if it's one-to-many, array_search will return an array of key's (spanish words) you'll have to choose from somehow.